Thriller where a teenager has an affair with his rich neighbor's wife
The movie is about a teenager (boy) who gets a small job from his rich neighbour. The job is to fix the man's boat. He then has an affair with the man's wife, but what the boy doesn't know is that the woman is using him just so she can get to her own husband's money.
At the end of the movie, if I remember correctly, she ends up getting the money and she then leaves with another girl in a car, while the boy gets caught by the police. The story overall is about the boy and how this was his mistake of his life and that love is dangerous. I also remember that the girl was blonde, and that the story took place in the summer. The first time the boy and the woman make out is in the rich man's kitchen. By that time, the man is away for a while doing bussiness or something 
The genre of the movie is mostly thriller, because everytime the boy and the woman are with each other, they almost get caught by the rich husband. The movie was released between 2000-2015.

I also remember that the girl was blonde, and that the story took place in the summer

The first time the boy and the woman make-out is in the rich man's kitchen. By that time, the man is away for a while doing bussiness or something

Sounds like Careful What You Wish For from 2015 with Nick Jonas.

A young man enters in an affair with a married woman, but things take a turn for the worse when he is forced to face his affair. Not only is he forced to face the consequence of the affair, he also spends most of his youth in prison; paying for a crime he did not commit. The married woman who is bisexual elopes with her lover in Hong Kong.

It starts when his rich neighbor asks him to fix his boat, and his wife is blonde. Here's the trailer:




Yes! Finally! Thank you :)
